# Konjunktiv II, du "wärst" or "wärest"?

Tags: verb, verb-choice

My german teacher taught us to use "du wärest", but I found some examples in my book in which "du wärst" is used as well.  (like this one: Wärst du so nett,..) 
What do you think about it? Are they both correct? Is one better than the other?

Comment: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sein_Hilfsverb

Comment: http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/sein_(Konjugation)

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wärst%2C+wärest&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cwärst%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwärst%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWärst%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cwärest%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwärest%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWärest%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both forms are equivalent, you can choose whichever you want.

Comment: "wärest" klingt etwas veraltet bzw. leicht poetisch.

Comment: In der gesprochenen Sprache wird nur die kürzere Form verwendet. In geschriebener Sprache ist wärest schon gehobener Stil.